# Java agent to display dynamically generated graphic?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, lotus-notes

In Lotus Notes, I have a document that contains a PPT file attachment. Using Apache POI, I was planning to generate an image from a specific slide from that PPT and display it on the web browser by accessing the agent from the web probably with the use of Ajax. Is there a way to temporarily store the generated image and display it? If yes, how would you be able to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this even without saving the attachment by encoding it Base64 and embedding it in the source-code like this:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,
R0lGODlhmwDFAPcAAAAAAAEBAQICAgMDAwQEBAUFBQYGBgcHBwgICAkJCQoKCgsLCwwMDA0N
DQ4ODg8PDxAQEBERERISEhMTExQUFBUVFRYWFhcXFxgYGBkZGRoaGhsbGxwcHB0dHR4eHh8f
HyAgICEhISIiIiMjIyQkJCUlJSYmJicnJygoKCkpKSoqKisrKywsLC0tLS4uLi8vLzAwMDEx
MTIyMjMzMzQ0NDU1NTY2Njc3Nzg4ODk5OTo6Ojs7Ozw8PD09PT4+Pj8/P0BAQEFBQUJCQkND

.... Lot of ascii characters ....

gww18FBEikHcgNkMRW5lmkJI/teaa0wNiOhshFFuiRSVpL34nqQRphZmcV5miORZQwnRpndI
nUmiiTStuaKbLl4Z45wuuADDDDfsgNKeMmy160w1hdaVSZfupyiXSgLoWpOQFjgpWUsKCGem
CEXFlIRlBefllxqKKlyblb45olWqosgmi29iGiudM+6Knp5F6LhrDYYCccQRQuzQp1cBAQA7">
```

If you need to store it, you could store it to a temp- folder and then attach it to a document. Then you could easily show it using an img- tag with src- url `http://server/db.nsf/_/documentuniqueidOfSavedDocument/$File/nameOfImage.jpg`

Comment: I used the first technique in my xpages barcode control (on openntf). Following doc explains how to work with graphics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I have already generated the image using the methods in the graphics2d class. From there I wrote it in png format, encoded it in base64, and output the img tag code.